# Default AspCore reset token contains illegal characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to setup reset tokens using custom blazor page.
The token generation works just fine, using

```
            var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

It generated the following code

```
CfDJ8HVZ73lJc0lGiTBiTdeoRRd//Zc1LM0Q4P+8t7DLaBzwlQ2DuvY2HQ5CWE/E8b3VdlZZYIelpwwrCFz579CeCcQTf+YIPli7KpPTuUpMcTHDs5pAw3XifV7x+5Y/Q6WAPdixXuHE8We9QQRxl7Hnba2vjoJ5fCZ9FMHKpkOq3mxDhgYi/gba2Vse3/R87ztVrisEguYvYQ8h5f2MAVMiCB+H0TakjKjpj2ANAD9wQ2H8
```

Sending it through the mail requires encoding as can bee seen at [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11943) , giving me

```
            var callbackUrl = _globals.AppUrl
            + "/user/reset/"
            + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
```

Now the mail send successfully, and the URL is successfully encoded.
However, when opening the page, I get an 404.11 error

```
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.
```

Page declaration:

```
@page "/user/reset/{Code}"
```

Example URL:

```
https://localhost:44303/user/reset/CfDJ8HVZ73lJc0lGiTBiTdeoRRfumtSdRgb46HPXLklW0j42IyjqN8rv%2fapJG158YfIrR7dVRNRF2YxJydegd2CMlvm93FTcjkuBwnVPC3N9AtSigiy8VOqeW1nNrRth73urJ23D0V6M2c%2fzE1%2bTuFs8KbB%2fnCG5CE3UnFXG5HleeA%2fwtlyzLgbP4Zrbi5XZ4Q0w4%2b1j83J%2fXvQUqg%2fO5raSkmcO3cb1TGnDWz%2fwqxW%2fbNOe
```

**Question**

Does ASP Core Identity include characters which cannot be sent by email by default? (I'd assume the '+' character). And can we exclude then from generation? Or is there another way to manipulate the URL preventing this error. I prefer to keep double escape character filter ON, as it increases security

**Edit**

When encoding the entire url as follows:

```
        var callbackUrl = _globals.AppUrl
            + "/user/reset/"
            + code;
        callbackUrl = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);
```

A 404 error occurs, because the code contains a '/', which does not fit my routing

Comment: That is not how I do it.   I would NOT encode the one portion.... I would create the entire url like this:var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Password", new { Area = AreaNames.Membership, code = code }, Request.Scheme);            Then I would enconde the entire url because it is going into an email like this: HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)

Comment: Also I am not sure you need to URL Encode it... More likely you need to Html Encode it.

Comment: you can try to  encode the token and then html encoding the full link not just the code .

Comment: @NanYu When i do that, it gives a 404, because the code contains a '/', which doesn't fit the routing

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro See updated post

Comment: I think you are building the url wrong.  Try to build it the way I showed you. I do this all the time.  The code I showed it from a working website.

Comment: Use Url.Action.  If this is for page use Url.Page

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro When I do this in the controller (not the page), r

Answer (score 0):

```
var callbackUrl =
            _globals.AppUrl
            + "/user/reset/"
            + code;
        **callbackUrl = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);**

**Update for this**

 var callbackUrl = _globals.AppUrl
            + "/user/reset/"
            + code;
        **callbackUrl = {callbackUrl};**
```